# Property's value (datetime) change from ajax call to mvc 4 controller method

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am passing a viewModel from ajax call like this:

```
       $.ajax("url", {
                data: JSON.stringify({ vm: ko.toJS(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(window.viewModel)) }),
                type: "POST",
                async: performAsyncCall !== undefined ? performAsyncCall : true,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                         //Code here

                },
                error: function (error) {
                         //Code here
                },
                complete: function () {
                         //Code here
                }
            });
```

And my controller method (using mvc 4) is like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Method(CustomViewModel vm)
        {
            //Code here
        }
```

window.viewModel (on javascript code) has a property called CreationDate equal to CustomViewModel (on c# code) who has a CreationDate property also. Before to do the post to the server from client, CreationDate has this value (6:48am):

[image: CreationDate client value]

But the same property has this value (2:48am) on server:

[image: CreationDate server value]

I need the value that is on client but i didn't found how it value is changing, somebody can help me?

Comment: That "Z" in the creation date means the time is in UTC, it is being converted to local time on your server.

Comment: Yes, but i need it in UTC on server too.

Comment: 02:48:02 on your server in local time *is* 06:48:02 in UTC - the only difference is what is being displayed. If you want to convert a local `DateTime` instance to UTC, use the `ToUniversalTime` method.

You're likely better off using `DateTimeOffset` rather than `DateTime` in your model one way or the other, but no information is being lost in what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, i know. See, i have passed the CreationDate value to client before save its value on database. If i set the value of CreationDate on the server i will change the real creation date everytime. I need that client pass to the server the creation date i have passed from the server to save it on the database and never change it again.

Comment: More brief: I am initializing the model with this value on the server first but the problem is passing the value back to server to save it on database.

Answer (score 0):

Send TimeZone offset as well and you'll know what the user time offset is. Use `getTimezoneOffset()` on JavaScript `Date` object. [Documentation](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/date.shtml)

If you don't want to change your model you can simply add additional parameter to your action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method(CustomViewModel vm, int timezoneOffset)
{
     //Code here
}
```

In JS:

```
var toSend = ko.toJS(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(window.viewModel));
$.ajax("url", {
         data: JSON.stringify({ vm: toSend, timezoneOffset: toSend.CreationDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60 }),
         type: "POST",
         async: performAsyncCall !== undefined ? performAsyncCall : true,
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (result) {
                  //Code here
          },
         error: function (error) {
                  //Code here
         },
         complete: function () {
                  //Code here
         }
     });
```